# ASP.Net pages hangs on white screen while CPU is almost zero

Tags: asp.net, freeze

I know that the answer of this question is more a "guidance tip" than a "ready-to-deploy" solution...but this scenario seems weird to me

I have a ASP.Net Web Application (framework 1.1) running under IIS 6.0. The users are complaining about performance issues, than I started monitoring the server.

The server has up to 4GB RAM and up to 4 processors...while monitoring, I noticed that the memory peaks are 2gb and the processing is 35% (not so bad). **Important:** This server has other websites running on it.

So, looking at IIS log files hasn't helped me...I asked the users to show me their screen, and thats what I could see:

When the users makes a request (any request, even a post-back) IE starts the request, the progress bar starts to load very slowly, IEs screen becomes white and stays like this for a while (some seconds)...after this, suddenly the page is rendered completely, the progress bar goes to the end quite fast (not like before).

During the request, I observed the server processes...the IIS process that serves the application stayed on low memory usage (over 200mb) and low CPU usage (like 2% almost all the time)...When the page has rendered, the CPU increased to 30% and the page finished its loading...

I'd like to know what more to investigate...For me it seems that the requests are being queued, and as it gets processed it works fine...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with other browsers? Just to see if it's a client or server issue.

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler, and in the IE dev tools network timing?

Comment: @AndreaCarrer I can't use other browsers, this is a intranet web app, and IE is the supported browser.

Comment: @SLaks In Fiddler I cant see the requests/responses returning correctly (HTTP 200)...I could not found the network timing tab, or menu...can you help me?